# Kumantech 3.5" LCD Touch Display, Python Library

Tags: python, display, touchscreen

I've a [Kumantech 3,5" LCD Touch Display](http://www.kumantech.com/kuman-35quot-320480-tft-lcd-display-with-case-for-raspberry-pi-pi-2-pi-3-model-b-sc11_p0162.html) in front of me. I'm trying to find a python library to controll the LCD, because i don't want to use x or just to console. I couldn't find any. And I couldn't find any information about the used LCD Controller, to find a lib for this one. So I want to ask you guys, if you have any information about it. :)

With best regards,
Benjamin

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use X, but you will certainly need a driver which can talk to the display and provide you with a framebuffer device. It seems that you can download a driver form your seller [here](http://www.kumantech.com/help/documents-and-recources_h0037.html).

Then you can use the framebuffer to draw on the LCD using `fbpy` or `pygame`.